# How does flutter make textfield dynamically display multiple lines?

Tags: flutter, textfield, flutter-layout

The effect I want to achieve is that the initial text field displays one line, and when the content exceeds one line, the text field displays two lines. The problem is that the baseline of the text field will move down, causing it to be obscured by the widget below. I want the baseline to remain in a row.

[image]

[image]

code:

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(
              maxHeight: 60.0
            ),
            child: TextField(
              maxLines: null,
              maxLengthEnforced: false,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
            ),
          ),
          Container(height: 20.0,width: 200.0,color: Colors.red),
        ],
      )
    );
```

The expected effect should be:

One line of text effect:

[image]

Multi-line text effect:

[image]

Note that the baseline position has not moved down.

Comment: Simply set property `maxLines: 1` for TextField

Comment: If so, it will always show only one row. I want the text field to display two lines when the content exceeds two lines, which can change dynamically depending on the content. In fact, my code has already achieved this effect, but the textfield's baseline will move down, causing the text to be occluded.

Answer (score 14):

Just set the *maxLines* property to **null**. The *TextField* Widget will automatically wrap the text, changing the number of lines dynamically.

[Documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TextField/maxLines.html)